# CiviCRM identifies itself over SMTP as 'localhost' while sending CiviMail via CLI

Tags: civimail

CiviCRM should say ...

```
EHLO example.com
```

... in the SMTP dialogue as it sends email. And it does when the email is being sent via a browser.

But when the email is being send via a CLI batch job, CiviCRM says ...

```
EHLO localhost
```

... which some email hosts interpret as a SPAM source.

Any thoughts?

Comment: The cause is at https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Utils/Mail.php#L72

Answer (score 1):

I created CRM-20982 to fix this